# Make Vim show ALL white spaces as a character

Tags: vim, whitespace, vi, hidden-characters

I can't find a way to make Vim show all white spaces as a character.
All I found was about tabs, trailing spaces etc.

Comment: I’m also trying to solve exactly this problem. Please, if you come across this, refrain from making yet another response involving `:set list`. That doesn’t answer our question. (To other comers: [mrucci](http://stackoverflow.com/users/133106/mrucci)’s response below is helpful, though not quite a real *solution*.)

Comment: For all of those who say that spaces are visible with `list` and `listchars` consider that a space is directly following a tab.  It would be nearly invisible in this situation.  I agree that you can catch most situations but if would be nice to have proper highlighting of all spaces.

Comment: For new visitors: **_This is solved in newer versions of vim!_ See [brettanomyces](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1427295/brett)'s [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675688/make-vim-show-all-white-spaces-as-a-character/29787362#29787362).**

Comment: Related (but difference stack): http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/422/displaying-tabs-as-characters

Answer (score 777):

As others have said, you could use

```
:set list
```

which will, in combination with

```
:set listchars=...
```

display invisible characters.
Now, there isn't an explicit option which you can use to *show* whitespace, but in listchars, you could set a character to show for everything BUT whitespace. For example, mine looks like this

```
:set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
```

so, now, after you use

```
:set list
```

everything that isn't explicitly shown as something else, is then, really, a plain old whitespace.

As usual, to understand how `listchars` works, use the help. It provides great information about what chars can be displayed (like trailing space, for instance) and how to do it:

```
:help listchars
```

It might be helpful to add a toggle to it so you can see the changes mid editing easily (source: [VIM :set list! as a toggle in .vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534313/vim-set-list-as-a-toggle-in-vimrc)):

```
noremap <F5> :set list!<CR>
inoremap <F5> <C-o>:set list!<CR>
cnoremap <F5> <C-c>:set list!<CR>
```

Comment: “everything that isn't explicitly shown as something else”? Try out unicode spaces from range U+2000..U+200A. If fixed-width font supports them they will be shown just as normal 0x20 space.

Comment: @ZyX - I was't taking the whole of Unicode, but the rather common set of characters in use. If you're unsatisfied with the answer, feel free to suggest improvements.

Comment: Great tip! I recommend to put the _set listchars_ line to the `.vimrc` file, so this pretty way of displaying invisible characters can be easily enabled with `:set list` in any time (without googling this page again).

Comment: @ckarbass  Same way you toggle anything in vim - adding a ! to the end.   So it becomes :set list!

Comment: Let's look again at the ALL-part. I'm searching for visualization of all spaces while everything mentioned here only works for tabs and trailing spaces. Anyone have any suggestions for showing ALL spaces?

Comment: I used middle dot `·` for white spaces and my VIM now looks awesome! Thanks for the tip~

Answer (score 386):

As of patch [7.4.710](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/adf123f0d55bbbe59dc139ede876431349446dd3) you can now set a character to show in place of space using listchars!

```
:set listchars+=space:␣
```

So, to show **ALL** white space characters as a character you can do the following:

```
:set listchars=eol:¬,tab:>·,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:␣
:set list
```

When you are finished, to hide the non-visible chars you would:

```
:set nolist
```

Discussion on mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/vim_dev/pjmW6wOZW_Q

Comment: This is pretty cool, but I'm wondering why the eol character doesn't get colourised differently, unlike the others.

Comment: I tried this and got an error at first. It turned out that "space" was not a valid option in the slightly older version of gvim I was using. Upgrading my gvim solved my problem. For others that are getting an error, type `:help listchars` to check whether "space" is a valid option for "listchars". If it is not, upgrade your vim to the patch @brettanomyces specified. Or just leave "space" out of the set command if you don't care to see spaces.

Comment: Works great. My only wish you could set the color to be a bit lighter so the space characters are less distracting.

Comment: I use Unicode's Middle Dot (U+00B7) for space character (`space:·`), as it looks like MS Word, Notepad++, etc.

Comment: I keep getting errors with the character chosen here for `space`; `E474: Invalid argument: listchars+=space:�~P�`. Looks like something about this character is not working properly when I either write it directly to my .vimrc from my local desktop, or copy/paste it into the terminal as a command within vim. I am using vim 7.4

Comment: @user5359531 try <ctrl-v>u2334 to enter the unicode open box character (␣). See https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/special-characters-in-vim/ for more details

Comment: Thanks, looks like I was actually still out of date, on version 7.4.629 (had to start vim with no file and type `:version` to find out). A combination of installing my [own user local vim](https://superuser.com/a/228376/529900) and adding [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18321539/5359531) items to my `.vimrc` has fixed it.

Comment: Type `<C-K>.M` in vim for `·`. See `:h digraph` for details.

Comment: maybe someone likes my choice of symbols: `set listchars=tab:⇤–⇥,space:·,trail:·,precedes:⇠,extends:⇢,nbsp:×`

Comment: And if using emacs, all you would do was M-x whitespace-mode. Man, I sometimes miss emacs.

Comment: I like this answer, except I also swapped it out with the dot character for spaces. A little easier to read.

```:set listchars=eol:¬,tab:>·,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:⋅```

Comment: It's too bad that RHEL7 runs an older version.

Answer (score 278):

`:set list` to enable.

`:set nolist` to disable.

Comment: Thank you for showing us how to toggle between modes. You'd think other advanced answers would teach that.

Comment: yes this is helpful. I wish it was the top answer as I found this answer myself only to find that it was already on the site, just out of view.

Comment: `: set list!` is better :)

Comment: @Skippr By what measure? It's same number of key presses, except that `Shift` and `!` are both harder to type than `no`. If you're putting it in your .vimrc, I agree that the exclam form is easier to read.

Comment: @Dan If you are looking to toggle this off and on in a relatively short time, `:set list!` will do so without you ever needing to enter `nolist`. The `!` simply does the opposite of whatever is currently set. I use this all the time especially when with `:set paste!`. I hate pressing the arrow key to find `:set paste` or `:set nopaste` lol

Answer (score 220):

I think other answers here are more comprehensive, but I thought I'd share a trick I usually use to differentiate tabs and spaces visually:

```
:syntax on
:set syntax=whitespace
```

These are syntax highlighting rules for the [Whitespace programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29) - tabs show in green and spaces in red. :)

Can be combined with `:set list` as mentioned by many other answers, although the tabs will then show as ^I without a green higlight, but the spaces will show in red.

Comment: I like this one, it is quite clever, and feels somehow better than most of the other answers. Not really a solution that's usable all the time, though.

Comment: I prefer more conventional methods, but I'm +1'ing this for inventiveness.

Comment: I knew that language would be useful for *something*.

Comment: Do you mind linking to the .vim syntax file you're using to highlight

Comment: @SeldomNeedy you shouldn't need to download anything, the whitespace highlighting rules have been shipping with Vim for years. They should essentially be built-in unless you're using a weird or really old version of Vim.

Comment: I really like this answer. Been looking for something exactly like this for a while.

Comment: To be able to return to the original syntax setting: 
`:syntax on`,  then 
`:setlocal syntax?` (take a note of the result, e. g. "syntax=go"),
`:set syntax=whitespace`, then (when done looking at whitespace;)  
`:set syntax=go`

Comment: mysys - does not include the built in rules atleast my experience

Answer (score 105):

`:set list` will show all whitespaces as a character. Everything *but* a space will look different than its normal state, which means that if you still see a plain old space, it's really a plain old space. :)

Comment: Turn this back off with `:set nolist`

Comment: What if you want to see the space character, like in Sublime Text 2 with "show whitespace" on? I found it really helpful.

Comment: Not what I came here for but very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Also options with no could be toggled with `!` at the end: `set list!`

Comment: I was looking to set the `space` character which it seems you do with `space:•` when setting `listchars`.

Mine looks like this:
---
`set showbreak=↪\ `
`set listchars=tab:→\ ,eol:↲,nbsp:␣,trail:•,extends:⟩,precedes:⟨,space:•`

Answer (score 75):

If you set:

```
:highlight Search cterm=underline gui=underline ctermbg=none guibg=none ctermfg=none guifg=none
```

and then perform a search for a space, every space character will be shown as an underline character.

You can use this command in a handy function that toggles "underscoring" of spaces.

```
set hls
let g:HLSpace = 1
let g:HLColorScheme = g:colors_name
function ToggleSpaceUnderscoring()
    if g:HLSpace
        highlight Search cterm=underline gui=underline ctermbg=none guibg=none ctermfg=none guifg=none
        let @/ = " "
    else
        highlight clear
        silent colorscheme "".g:HLColorScheme
        let @/ = ""
    endif
    let g:HLSpace = !g:HLSpace
endfunction
```

Map the function to a shortcut key with:

```
nmap <silent> <F3> <Esc>:call ToggleSpaceUnderscoring()<CR>
```

*NB:* Define the function in vimrc after the colorscheme has been set.

Comment: Well, it’s a bit of a hack, but it’s closer than anything else so far. Bounty awarded! :D

Answer (score 48):

Depending on your syntax rules for the current buffer, something like this could work:

```
:syn match WhiteSpace / / containedin=ALL conceal cchar=Æ
:setl conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nv
```

This needs a vim 7.3 with +conceal feature

**Update 10/24/2014**
To expand a little bit on that. It is of course possible to define some highlighting for the conealed characters.

- You can configure, how the concealed chars look. For highlighting, you would have to at least once configure the 'Conceal' highlighting group (See the help at `:h hl-Conceal` This can be done in your colorscheme and then you do not need to reconfigure it again. But this affects all concealed chars (e.g. if your syntax script conceals some more items, they will be displayed as your white space chars). That could look like this:

  `:hi Conceal ctermfg=7 ctermbg=NONE guifg=LightGrey guibg=NONE`
- There seems to be a particularity that Vim will not highlight spaces, if the syntax script uses the `skipwhite` keyword. There will be no way around (perhaps this will be fixed, I posted a [patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/sSkuUhSDX6o/fEWBkaseeoUJ))
- There seems to be a patch floating around, that will allow to customize how spaces will look in `list` mode. The latest one at the time of writing seems to be [this one](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/dIQHjW1g92s/CtBo6MfNXN4J). (This means, you need to built your own Vim to use this).
- The `conceallevel` and `concealcursor` are window local options. That means they can be different in different windows (and will possibly be also set by filetype plugins or other plugin scripts).
- The syntax highlighting groups need to be executed whenever a syntax definition file is reloaded. This could be done using a `BufWinEnter`or possibly also a `Syntax` or even `FileType` autocommand. (I have not tested which one actually works).

The last two items means, you would have to setup some autocommands that reset the syntax rules and the correesponding options. For the first one, one might want to setup the highlighting using a `ColorScheme` autocommand (so that the concealed chars always look the same, independent of what a color scheme actually sets up). For a complete solution, look into romainl answer, that should give you a start. If you setup a function, you can easily setup a toggle command to switch displaying special Highlighting on or off.

**Update 10/26/2014** I made a [plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-show-whitespace) out of this question.

**Update 04/22/2015** A patch has been included in Vim that makes this possible using the `list` option. Simply set `set list listchars+=space:␣` 
This works as of [Vim 7.4.711](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/Y-ATIo3du_c/LviJGkgdDGIJ)

Comment: This works great!  How can this be added to `.vimrc`?

Comment: Since this works on the current buffer, you probably need to wrap this into an autocommand. BufEnter or even Syntax autocommand might work for you:

Comment: `Æ` is a strange choice of character for this, why not `·`?

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Any ideas on how to add proper syntax highlighting to this character? I would prefer it if it were  a very faded ·

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, you have a bunch of trailing nrrwrgn-related files polluting your repo.

Answer (score 31):

I use this

```
/\s
:set hlsearch
```

to highlight white spaces. It searches for all white spaces, and then enables the highlight to make them pop out. However, it does **not** print a special character.

Comment: Simplest solution imho. Great paired with a command to clear search (I use `nnoremap <leader><space> :noh<cr>`)

Answer (score 25):

If by whitespaces you mean the ' ' character, my suggestion would just be a search/replace.  As the others have hinted, `set list` changes *non printing* characters to a visible character that's configured in `listchars`.

To explicitly show spaces as some other character, something similar to the below should do the trick:

`:%s/ /█/g`

Then just undo the change to go back again.

(to get the █ I pressed this exact key sequence: <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>CTRL-K</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>)

Comment: I like this better than other answers, this looks like inverse of `:set list` to me, changing visible character ('space') to a _non priting_(??) one. I wonder if one can use this inside match e.g. `:match MyBlackBlockChar "appropriate_regex` that should do the trick, shouldn't it?

Comment: The other answers are useful, but this is the first one that actually answers OP's question +1

Comment: Or `:%s/\s/█/g` for all whitespace. Also, `:set hlsearch` plus `:&s/\s//gn` might be useful.

Answer (score 16):

To highlight spaces, just search for it:

/<space>

Notes:

<space> means just type the space character.

Enable highlighting of search results with :set hlsearch

To highlight spaces & tabs:
/[<space><tab>]

A quick way to remove the highlights is to search for anything else:
/asdf

(just type any short list of random characters)

Comment: This is the same as the answer posted 3 years earlier.  Also, :noh is quicker than /asdf for unhighlighting text. Or you could even set f1 to :noh given that you'll probably be using it often.

Comment: @DrEval Assuming you're referring to [Benedikt Köppel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8280159/327074) it's actually subtly different `/<space>` vs `/\s`. I think it's non-obvious and faster to use the suggestion here.

Answer (score 16):

The code below is based on Christian Brabandt's answer and seems to do what the OP wants:

```
function! Whitespace()
    if !exists('b:ws')
        highlight Conceal ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=240 cterm=NONE guibg=NONE guifg=#585858 gui=NONE
        highlight link Whitespace Conceal
        let b:ws = 1
    endif

    syntax clear Whitespace
    syntax match Whitespace / / containedin=ALL conceal cchar=·
    setlocal conceallevel=2 concealcursor=c
endfunction

augroup Whitespace
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter,WinEnter * call Whitespace()
augroup END
```

Append those lines to your `~/.vimrc` and start a new Vim session to see the *still imperfect* magic happen.

Feel free to edit the default colors and conceal character.

---

Caveat: something in the `*FuncBody` syntax group in several languages prevents the middle dot from showing. I don't know (yet?) how to make that solution more reliable.

Comment: That's what I meant with "depending on the syntax group" I suspect this is a problem with syn keywords in combination with the skipwhite flag.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, yeah, I couldn't go beyond what you already did beside making it "automatic".

Comment: Yes, it's the `skipwhite` argument in the syntax rules, that prevents the syntax group to match (although it should be allowed to be contained in all groups).

Comment: Is there any way to make this work nicely with [Indent Guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides), which adds background to indentation? I suspect it's a matter of getting this to no override the background color, but this seems to be non-trivial.

Comment: How to disable the same when highlighting of white space are not required? Looking for kind of short toggle command.

Answer (score 12):

I didn't find exactly what I wanted from the existing answers. The code below will highlight all trailing spaces bright red. Simply add the following to your `.vimrc`

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```

Answer (score 11):

I was frustrated with all of the other answers to this question, because none of them highlight the space character in a useful way. Showing spaces as characters would particularly help for whitespace-formatted languages, where mixing tabs and spaces is harmful.

My solution is to show tabs and underline multiple spaces. It borrows from [mrucci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675771/610632) and [this tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces). Because it uses syntax highlighting, it's persistent:

```
set list listchars=tab:\|\ 
highlight Whitespace cterm=underline gui=underline ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE ctermfg=yellow guifg=yellow
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight Whitespace gui=underline ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE ctermfg=yellow guifg=yellow
match Whitespace /  \+/
```

Using this, tabs are displayed as `|` and spaces as `_`, which makes it very easy to tell when I'm mixing code styles.

The only downside I've found is that this snippet doesn't adjust background color to match the context (like in a comment).

Answer (score 11):

To cover Unicode whitespace characters:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:│\ ,nbsp:·
highlight StrangeWhitespace guibg=Red ctermbg=Red
" The list is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37903645 (with `\t`, `\n`, ` `, `\xa0` removed):
call matchadd('StrangeWhitespace', '[\x0b\x0c\r\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x85\u1680\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000]')
```

The result:

- Only the ordinal space (U+0020) looks like an ordinal space (" ").
- The tab (U+0009) looks like "`│` " (two characters: a long pipe and then an ordinal space; they are gray in `colorscheme murphy`).
- The non-breaking space (U+00A0) looks like "`·`" (one character; it's gray in `colorscheme murphy`).
- Any other whitespace character looks like a red space (" ").

Comment: Edited to add "ctermbg=Red" to make my terminal to work for the coloring.  Personally I used `set listchars=tab:»\ ,space:·` for your reference.

Comment: @JohnnyWong Thanks for the update. It was initially rejected by reviewers, but I've checked the code, and it (unsurprisingly) works both for `gvim` and `vim`.

Comment: Brilliant answer, this is exactly what I needed to capture narrow non-break spaces (Hex 202f) that don't get rendered in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Perfect solution. I however replaced `Red` with `Brown`, as red is already used a lot in many places (and I already use it to show trailing whitespace).

Answer (score 9):

all of the answers above try to make spaces visible from within vim. If you really insist on having visible spaces as dots, there's another approach...

If it cannot be done in vim, change your font entirely. I copied the Ubuntu One Mono font and edited it using FontForge. Remember to change the font's fullname, family, preferred family, compatible full (in FontFoge it's under TTF Names in the font info), in order to have it as a separate font.
Simply edit the space character to have a dot in the middle and save the font to ~/.fonts
Now you can use it for your gvim or the entire terminal...
I copied the "!" character, removed the line and moved the dot to the middle. It took a little more than 5 minutes...

Note: changing the space character (0x20) results in the inconvenience of having dots on the entire vim screen... (but it will separate the spaces from tabs...)

Comment: This sounded like a really good approach until I read the note about filling the entire screen with dots. :/

Comment: Points for creativity! :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
:set list
```

to really see the structure of a line. You will see tabs and newlines explicitly. When you see a blank, it's really a blank.

Answer (score 5):

```
:match CursorLine /\s\+/
```

avoids the "you have to search for spaces to get them to show up" bit but afaict can't be configured to do non-hilighting things to the spaces.  CursorLine can be any hilighting group and in the default theme it's a plain underline.

Comment: I can't tell the difference between tabs and spaces using this method, which is too bad, but I love that it's a one liner.

Answer (score 5):

I like using special characters to show whitespace, is more clear. Even a map to toggle is a key feature, for a quick check.

You can find this features in an old vim script not updated since 2004:

[vim-scripts/cream-showinvisibles@vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=363)

Thanks to project [vim-scripts](http://vim-scripts.org/) and [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) you can come back to life this plugin

[vim-scripts/cream-showinvisibles@github](https://github.com/vim-scripts/cream-showinvisibles)

Even better, my two cents on this is to add a [configurable shortcut](https://github.com/albfan/cream-showinvisibles/commit/7086a50f42bdac98389ec66fa1fafad475a7a85f) (instead of predefined <kbd>F4</kbd>)

so add this to *~/.vimrc*

```
Plugin 'albfan/cream-invisibles'

let g:creamInvisibleShortCut = "<F5>" "for my F4 goto next error
```

install plugin on vim

```
:PluginInstall
```

and there you go

Answer (score 5):

Keep [those hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787362/65706) in the .vimrc as comments, so in the shell, simply :

```
echo '
  " how-to see the non-visible while spaces
  " :set listchars=eol:¬,tab:>·,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:␣
  " set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
  " :set list
  " but hei how-to unset the visible tabs ?!
  " :set nolist
  ' >> ~/.vimrc
```

Answer (score 4):

highlight search

```
:set hlsearch
```

in `.vimrc` that is

and search for space tabs and carriage returns

```
/ \|\t\|\r
```

or search for all whitespace characters

```
/\s
```

of search for all non white space characters (the whitespace characters are not shown, so you see the whitespace characters between words, but not the trailing whitespace characters)

```
/\S
```

to show all trailing white space characters - at the end of the line

```
/\s$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:se list
:se nolist
```

`:se` is enough, `:set` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can also highlight the spaces (replacing the spaces with a block):

```
:%s/ /█/g
```

(before writing undo it)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to my .vimrc works for me. Just make sure you don't have anything else conflicting..

```
autocmd VimEnter * :syn match space /\s/
autocmd VimEnter * :hi space ctermbg=lightgray ctermfg=black guibg=lightgray guifg=black
```