# Vim - keeping track of exact whitespace counts

Tags: vim, whitespace

In both Eclipse and Notepad++, I have my text editors configured so a space has a semi-transparent dot in the center, which makes it easy to count whitespace. I prefer to use spaces instead of tabs in my text editing, and this feature is crucial when working with a whitespace-sensitive language like Python.

I have attached a screenshot with some dummy code in case my wording wasn't clear.

At any rate, is there any way to come close to this functionality in Vim (or GVim)? I suppose there is [highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998582/show-whitespace-characters-in-gvim) but that does seem a bit subpar. There's also good old fashioned math by looking at the column number. What are my other options?

[image: whitespace example]

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/vim_dev/dIQHjW1g92s

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675688/make-vim-show-all-white-spaces-as-a-character) notorious question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thes lines in your vimrc should give you an approximation but you won't get dots for normal or leading space: only trailing spaces. That's a Vim limitation.

```
set list
set listchars=
set listchars+=tab:»\ 
set listchars+=extends:› 
set listchars+=precedes:‹ 
set listchars+=nbsp:· 
set listchars+=trail:·
```

See `:help 'list'` and `:help 'listchars`.

Comment: You can also separate these via comma, ```set listchars=tab:»\ ,extends:›,precedes:‹,nbsp:·,trail:·```

Comment: sigh. sounds like the full support is not a priority at all for the developers, judging by the google thread (despite that it's a common feature in modern text editors). I'll accept this unless a better solution comes along in a day or two.

Comment: You can leave the question open, I don't mind. `highlight` seems dirtier but might be a viable alternative in the mean time.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with romainl's answer, but would like to add a mention of the [indent guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides), which can colour indentation based on your current tab size settings.

Comment: I copied the plugin, autoload, and doc dirs to my .vim directory but can't get the plugin to initialize. also tried adding a source statement and failed. How do I load it?

Comment: Do `:IndentGuidesEnable` in a Vim window or add it to your `.vimrc`. Since I only use the plug-in for Python I have the following in `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`:

    `let g:indent_guides_start_level=2\n
    let g:indent_guides_guide_size=1\n
    IndentGuidesEnable`

... (\n only for illustration purposes) but you can customize as you see fit. :)

Comment: :IndentGuidesEnable works within Vim but not when I add it to .vimrc (with or without colon)

Comment: That's because plug-ins are loaded after vimrc is processed. Maybe just enable it for specific file types, as described in my previous comment...?