# VIM: spaces/tab indentation

Tags: vim, tabs, whitespace, indentation, space

Is something like this possible with VIM (using Solarized Dark)?

If yes, with which package/config commands?

[image: vim]

Comment: What is "something like this"? Being able to see the spaces as visible dots? If so, go read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998582/show-whitespace-characters-in-gvim).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I found a solution. But it feel kinda hacky. Perhaps someone got a better solution?

I added this to my .vimrc

```
 hi Conceal ctermfg=239
 setl conceallevel=2 concealcursor=n
 autocmd InsertEnter,InsertLeave,BufReadPost * :syn match WhiteSpace / / containedin=ALL conceal cchar=·
```