# Vim: How to display soft tabs spaces as any other invisible characters?

Tags: vim, text-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Vim show ALL white spaces as a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675688/make-vim-show-all-white-spaces-as-a-character)

I’ve read the documentation & search on the Internet and I’ve not found yet a way to display the spaces used for indentation while using soft tabs settings. Someone have a solution for that?

Comment: Thanks! Didn’t find this post while searching here. My answer is in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675688/make-vim-show-all-white-spaces-as-a-character/6279316#6279316)