# showing single space invisible character in vim

Tags: vim

I have added `set listchars=tab:»\,trail:·,extends:#,nbsp:.` for showing invisible characters.

It is working for tab extends but not working for nbsp, I have read the help for `:set listchars` and tried with examples given there, but still I am not getting dot character for single space character.

what else I have to do for this. Any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Single spaces can't really be made visible with Vim. Check out the answers and workarounds [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675688/make-vim-show-all-white-spaces-as-a-character).

Comment: @glts, What does "single space" mean exactly? Does it just mean an ordinary space (x20)? Can't you just do `set listchars=space:·` and `set list`?

Answer (score 5):

Please be careful with the backslashes.

```
set listchars=tab:>\\,trail:·,extends:#,nbsp:.
```

This works as expected.  However, one should note that `nbsp` stands for non-breakable space (character 0xA0).  It's different from ordinary whitespaces (character 0x20) and in most cases, we'll have to do `Ctrl-v x a 0` in insert mode to type it.

Comment: @shinkou The command to insert a literal no-break space (U+00A0) is `CTRL-V xa0` or `CTRL-V u00a0`.

Comment: @gits True, I missed the "x".  Thanks.  :)

Comment: @dearvivekkumar Please see gits' comment.

Comment: Is there some alternative by which I can show for space character(0x20)??

Answer (score 5):

More recent versions of vim can show regular spaces as well. (Confirmed on vim 7.4.1689).

```
:set list
:set listchars=tab:→\ ,space:·,nbsp:␣,trail:•,eol:¶,precedes:«,extends:»
```

Comment: Could you tell me which font I should use to print `•` ? It is broken for me as you see [here](https://i.redd.it/ez53d0o54hf31.png).

Comment: I'm not sure, it worked for me with the default font. The character in your comment is `•` U+2022 "bullet". You could try `·` U+00B7 "middle dot" instead. Or scan through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters to find any character you like. You can also use a [unicode converter](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter) to copy and paste a character to lookup its code.