# How can I make vim show spaces?

Tags: vim

I'm currently trying to switch from gedit to vim. I try to make vim look similar to gedit:

[image: gedit]

Especially, I would like to show spaces with dots.

I currently have:

[image]

There are some differences, but it looks quite similar (this is [my current .vimrc file](https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/5346080)). But I don't get those dots for spaces.

**How can I make vim show spaces?**

I found some answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676514/562769)) that seem to suggest to replace spaces by a special visible character and then replace it back. I don't want to do this every time. I want to be able to open vim and see those spaces.

Comment: Vim Wikia article on [highlighting unwanted spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) might get you started...

Comment: I don't think it can be highlighted as a character, but you can highlight the background rather easily

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Vim show ALL white spaces as a character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675688/make-vim-show-all-white-spaces-as-a-character)

Comment: "see those spaces" for what purpose?

Comment: mainly because I'm used to see them

Comment: Type ":set list" or ":unset list" to show/hide non-space whitespace, keeping you sane in python under vim. But what you _really_ want is to switch to PyCharm. Honestly. It is the only way to code python. Says who? I do. Opinion. Sorry. But a strong one, from a longterm Linux fanboy who codes a lot of python and does almost everything else in vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim has been providing the `'listchars'` option to show Tab vs. Space, and space characters in critical places, i.e. trailing at the end of lines. In previous versions (when the question was written), it did not offer a modification for *all* spaces: a blank square is a space, period. Other answers provided some workarounds, though.

In current Vim versions, there are many space-related options; cp. [`:help 'listchars'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27listchars%27) for details.

You can get the effect seen in your screenshot; persist by putting that command into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:set list listchars+=space:. listchars-=eol:$
```

Comment: Your answer seems to contradict ernix answer. Is your answer wrong? It this is the case, you might want to delete it.

Comment: ernix answer is just another variation of the linked workarounds. The fact that you're struggling to get it to work shows its limitations already.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought the reason why I am struggeling to get it to work might be that I am just beginning to learn vim.

Answer (score 69):

Show non-space whitespace with

```
set list
```

Additionally show spaces as `.` with

```
set lcs+=space:·
```

Turn it off with

```
set nolist
```

Comment: Worked for Vi on Ubuntu. Thanks! @martin above should be updated as answer.

Comment: This solution along with 'set list' worked perfectly for me.

Comment: is there a way to toggle it?

Comment: @ivan0biwan try `set nolist`

Comment: @ivan0biwam try `set list!`

Comment: interesting.  "set lcs+=space:·" did not work for me on ubuntu.

Comment: @shawn1874 after `set lcs...` command, you might need to do `set list`.

Answer (score 37):

There are times when I absolutely need to see which whitespaces are tabs and which are true space characters, as well as when spaces appear at the end of a line.

When I'm using `vim`, I use:

```
:set list
```

(which I can turn off with `:set nolist`)

With `:set list`, literal spaces show up as spaces, tabs show up as `^I`, and the end-of-line shows up as a bright-pink `$`.  (So any blank space you see to the left of the pink `$` you'll know is a true space character, and the blank spaces to the right of it is just the "nothing" between the end-of-line and the right side of the editor.)

It's ugly, but it works well.

I don't recommend using it all the time -- just those times when it is crucial to see where literal spaces and literal tab characters exist.

Answer (score 13):

While you can't do exactly what you want here, if your reasoning is like mine, you're wanting to see those spaces because it helps verify proper indentation (do I have 2 spaces there, or is it 3?). For Vim >= 7.3, you can use the [**indentLine**](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) plugin to add a marker at each indentation. It's awesome.

To install if you're using [**Pathogen**](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen):

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It may be worth using `undercurl` to do the job.

```
hi WhiteSpaces gui=undercurl guifg=LightGray
match WhiteSpaces / \+/
```

or you can put this in your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight WhiteSpaces gui=undercurl guifg=LightGray | match WhiteSpaces / \+/
```

[image]

Comment: I've added these two lines to my `.vimrc`, but I don't get the spaces underlined. Do you know why?

Comment: Custom highlight settings will be cleared while changing `:colorscheme`. try following instead:

    autocmd ColorScheme * highlight WhiteSpaces gui=undercurl guifg=LightGray | match WhiteSpaces / \+/

Comment: It still doesn't work. Do I perhaps need to install plugins? How do I do so?

Comment: No need any external plugins.  Note that `undercurl` might be only available in GUI.

Answer (score 4):

Show leading spaces (indent spaces) using the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27556578/7311363) mentioned plugin [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine).
If you use [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) as plugin manager you can add `Plugin 'Yggdroot/indentLine'` to your `.vimrc` and then run `vim +PluginInstall +qall` to install the plugin.

Add the following two lines to your `.vimrc` to show leading spaces as `·`.

```
let g:indentLine_leadingSpaceChar='·'
let g:indentLine_leadingSpaceEnabled='1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the answers of J-L and Cedric Simon. Edit ~/.vimrc and add:

```
set lcs+=space:·
nmap <F2> :set invlist<CR>
imap <F2> <ESC>:set invlist<CR>a
```

and when you work with vim just pres `F2`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install any plugin to this:

```
set listchars=tab:\|\ 
"set listchars=tab:\┊\ 
"set listchars=tab:\┆\ 
"set listchars=tab:\¦\ 
set list
```