# Using listchars to show leading whitespace in Vim

Tags: vim, whitespace

I use spaces over tabs. In Sublime Text 2, I would have leading spaces show like so:

[image: leading spaces]

I have my .vimrc setup to show tabs, line endings, etc. But I'm not sure how to replicate what I have in Sublime. It was handy as I could still see indentation much more easily when just using spaces.

Here's my line for it now:

```
set listchars=eol:¬,tab:→→,extends:>,precedes:<
```

Comment: This is essentially asking for the same thing as [this popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1675688): it isn't possible. But there is [a patch pending](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/dIQHjW1g92s/FPUU_-9N3wYJ) on the devs mailing list: please make your voice heard there if you care for this feature being included in Vim.

Comment: You can workaround this. In your case something like this should work: `syn match LeadingWS /\(^\s*\)\@<=\s/ conceal cchar=·`. You need a Vim with the `+conceal` feature and you need to enable it: `:setlocal conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nv`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `list`+`listchars` combo can show *trailing* spaces but not *leading* spaces.

You could try [vim-indent-guide](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides).

Comment: The indent guide isn't entirely what i was looking for, but it essentially solves the same problem.