# How to highlight tabs and spaces in vim

Tags: vim, sublimetext, highlight

I want to highlight tabs and spaces. In sublime text I activated an `"draw_white_space": "all"` option. After that all tabs and spaces is highlighting.

[image]

I want to activate the same option in vim, but all what I used didn't work.

I tried set follow options:

```
set listchars=tab:--
set list
```

How is it possible to activate it, and how to make highlighting tabs and spaces the same sympols like in picture above?

Comment: Your tab highlight should (mostly) work as you like, now. Is something wrong with it? If it's just not as pretty as you want, you can use mdash characters or some Unicode drawing character in place of dashes. For the spaces, unfortunately, Vim does not have a built-in option (yet) but I think there is a patch available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As icwnd says use

```
set list
set listchars=tab:▸·
```

However you may find that you still cannot see the characters because they are the same color as the background. Adding the following will change the color of those characters

```
highlight NonText guifg=#4a4a59
highlight SpecialKey guifg=#4a4a59
```

As Ben mentions, this does not work for spaces.

---

Edit

You can now do the same for spaces, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787362/1427295.

Answer (score 5):

There is a vim plugin called [spacehi](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=443) which does that with tabs.

Download the `spacehi.vim` file, copy that into your `~/.vim/plugin/` folder, restart vim and activate/deactivate with `F3`.

If you don't want to use the plugin you could use this:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:--,trail:.,eol:¬,extends:>,precedes:<
```

For even nicer indentation also take a look at the [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides).