# How to test if I my setting in vi is tabs or spaces

Tags: vim, vi

I set the setting in the vi file to spaces, and I want to verify that it is working correctly is there a way to test it ?

I know it is a trivial question but I am new to vi editor

Comment: Try this answer: [Make Vim show ALL white spaces as a character](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29787362/5358968). Note this question belongs in the [vi and vim SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You could also just navigate using the arrow keys or `hjkl` and if your cursor jumps over an area, then it is a tab. If it moves one position at a time, then it is spaces.

Comment: The correct answer is fiddling with `:set list` but a quick way to test is, with `set hlsearch` on (which it should either way) just do `/ ` (that's a search with one space) or `/\t` to highlight tabs.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at `:set list` / `:help list`

you can set listchars like so:
`set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:< " mark all kinds of whitespace`

as an example, this setting will show tabs as `>` so you know where your tabs are.

useful links: 
[Make Vim show ALL white spaces as a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675688/make-vim-show-all-white-spaces-as-a-character)

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/See_the_tabs_in_your_file